# Page reloads again after clicking on the sign off button

Tags: javascript, c#, modal-dialog

How all,

I created a button inside of a modal header that when clicked, should log you off.  However, that is not happening.  When I click the button, the page reloads again with the modal appearing.  Does anyone know what could be causing this?

**This is how I have my modal set up.  Inside modal-header, I added the code so that when the user clicks on "x", it should sign them off.**

```
<div id="myModal2" class="modal fade" role="dialog" data-keyboard="false" data-backdrop="static">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content" style="text-align:center">
            <div class="modal-header">
                @using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { id = "formlogoff" }))
                {
                    <span name="requestVerificationToken">@Html.AntiForgeryToken()</span>
                    <button  id="signoff" class="close">x</button>
                }
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div>
                    <p>After the free trial you will automatically started your paid monthly subscriptio</p>
                </div>

                <input type="checkbox" name="ThirtyTrial" id="ThirtyTrial" class="filled-in chk-col-deep-orange" required>
                <label for="ThirtyTrial">Please do not show this to me again.</label>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer" style="text-align:center">
                <a class="modal-free-trial" onclick="createModal('@Url.Action("AddCustomer", "Billing")')">Add Payment</a>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

**This is my Ajax call for signing off**

```
   $('#signoff').on('click', function (event) {
        event.preventDefault()
        var form = $('#formlogoff');
        var token = $('input[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]', form).val();

        $.ajax({
            url: '/Account/LogOff',
            data: { __RequestVerificationToken: token },
            type: "POST",
            success: function (data) { window.location.href = '/Account/Login' }
        });
     });
```

Answer (score 1):

I removed event.preventDefault() from the the signoff function

Answer (score 0):

At the end of your `click` callback, can you try `return false;` e.g.

```
$('#signoff').on('click', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault()
    // ...

    $.ajax({
        // ...
    });

    return false;
 });
```

Comment: I did, but no luck. It still refreshes.